# How to insert a line every 10 numbers displayed in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to insert a line every 10 numbers displayed but when I run this and enter -29 and 29, not a single line shows. Please help and thank you

```
int start;
int end;
     
do 
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between -30 and 0: ";
    cin >>start;
} while(start > 0 || start < -30);
    
do 
{
    cout << "Pleaes enter a number between 15 and 30: ";
    cin >> end;
} while(end < 15 || end > 30);
        
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
    if (i++ % 10 == 0)
    {
        cout << "----------"<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout << start << " " << end <<endl;
}
```

Comment: The code is formatted in an incoherent style.  Please fix the formatting.

Comment: You are incrementing the `i` twice in the loop.  Don't increment the loop counter inside the loop. `if (i++ % 10 == 0)` should be `if (i % 10 == 0)`

Comment: `if (i++ % 10 == 0)` -- Writing a line like that gives all the indication that you lifted this very same line from another program without thinking about what it actually does.  It would be very difficult for anyone, even a beginner, to even think about writing a line of code like that (incrementing `i` before a modulus of an integer).  Every line of code you write, you must know **exactly** what the intentions are.

Comment: Stepping through the program line-by-line with a debugger and comparing the actions take aby the program against your expectations would have found the bug outlined above within a minute. The debugger is possibly second only to the compiler for improving programmer productivity, so the sooner you start using it, the sooner you reap the benefits.

Comment: I'm inclined to close this as a typo if this is indeed a case of "copying and pasting" from another program without the due diligence of checking the code.

Comment: This is not, by any means, a "copying and pasting" case. It is a homework I have been working on. And it is all my work and I genuinely didn't understand why it is `(i%10=0)` and not `(i++%10=0)`

Comment: @mgmourad  You should never modify the loop counter inside the loop.  The loop counter is controlled by the loop - if the contents of the loop change it then the loop has lost control.  (By "never" I obviously mean "almost never"  - there are some really rare cases where it makes sense but they are way out of beginner territory.)

Comment: @mgmourad *and I genuinely didn't understand why it is (i%10=0) and not (i++%10=0)* -- Not saying it isn't all your work.  But it is strange why a beginner would write `(i++%10 == 0)` and not the seemingly straightforward `(i%10 == 0)`.  Beginners write "easier" code first, and then find out their easy code won't work (if it doesn't work).  Seldom if at all have I found a beginner write "harder" code, and totally miss the easy, simple, "beginner" example.  That's why it looks like (and believe me, it isn't only myself) it was taken from another program you wrote without realizing what it did.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well, that's a new type of "beginner" for you to include in your experience. Thanks for the input anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` is incremented twice. Do not increment it again in the `if` condition, and just use the following:

`if (i % 10 == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

As said by Nimish Shah you're incrementing `i` twice. Besides, you're initialising `i` equal to `start`, that makes the code influenced by the value of `start`. Try to consider the following code instead:

```
for (int i = 0; start+i <= end; i++)
{
    cout << start << " " << end <<endl;
    
    if ((i+1) % 10 == 0)
    {
        cout << "----------"<<endl;

    }
}
```

In this way you print a line exactly after ten numbers